# Independence of an Infinite Number of R.V.s

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

An infinite collection of random variables $X_1, X_2, ...$ is said to be independent if every finite subcollection is. A finite subcollection of these random variables, say, $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ is said to be independent iff $$E\Big(\prod_{i=1}^{n}H_i(x_i)\Big) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} E(H_i(x_i)),$$ for any functions $H_1, H_2, ..., H_n$ (for which the right-hand member of the equation is defined).

How might I then prove that, if the infinite collection of random variables $X_1, X_2, ...$  is independent, then $$E\Big(\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}H_i(x_i)\Big) = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} E(H_i(x_i)),$$ for any functions  $H_1, H_2, ... $?

Comment: I doubt that this statement will always be true - it will be related to the reason why the independence is deliberately defined via finite subcollections. Unfortunately, I am not able to provide a counter-example, maybe someone else can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $H_i(x) = x$, and $P(x_i = 2) = P(x_i = -2) = 1/2$. Then $E(H_i(x_i)) = 0$, thus right side is just product of zeroes. But product on left side diverges almost surely, as common term doesn't go $1$, and so we can't even speak about its expectation.